# 'mongod' command not working in VS code powershell

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, visual-studio-code

The 'mongod' command to run mongodb server is not working in powershell of VS code editor, It is working perfectly fine in WindowsPowerShell and Command Prompt . The environment variable is also set to

[The VS Code error is as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTfls.png)

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, you are typing `monogod` (mon**o**god), not `mongod` - you have an extra `o` after the `n`.